# meaning of the phrase "gamble one's way"

Tags: meaning

I am aware that "gamble" means to risk or bet, bur I am puzzled by "gamble one's way." here it goes in context: "We are going to gamble our way to belief in God." Maybe the speaker left out "on" like "gamble on our wat," I am not sure. Tell me please what you think of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*VERB one's way to GOAL* is a fixed English construction (in fact it is one of the 'parade' examples analyzed by [Construction Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_grammar)) with the primary sense

- *proceed to GOAL **by** VERBing*—the action designated by *VERB* is the means or method of achieving *GOAL*

  > Go thrust him out at gates and let him **smell his way to Dover**—*said by Goneril in Shakespeare's* King Lear *after her husband has put out Gloucester's eyes; since Gloucester can no longer see he will have to discern his route by smell*.
  >
  > This Arkansas football player **danced his way to an NYU scholarship**—*a [news story](http://www.thv11.com/news/local/this-arkansas-football-player-danced-his-way-to-a-nyu-scholarship/446081966) about a high school athlete who achieved a scholarship at a prestigious New York university through his study of dance.*

The construction is also employed in a 'non-causative' sense

- *proceed to GOAL **while** VERBing*—the action designated by *VERB* accompanies progress toward *GOAL*

  > J. L. cheerfully whistled his way to the elevator. No sense in worrying about things that hadn't happened yet. —Cara Saylor Polk, [Code Koral](https://books.google.com/books?id=oZyLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT178&lpg=PT178&dq=%22whistled+his+way+to%22&source=bl&ots=yjMeJ9f_mx&sig=y6xB8ct0XfqPINkiyR1uSz7EsNk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDxd_o0qnWAhXKOSYKHeqEAlQQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=%22whistled%20his%20way%20to%22&f=false)

In your quotation the first, causative sense is probably what is meant: it seems to echo [Pascal's wager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_Wager) and Samuel Butler's comment on Job 19:25, *I know that my Redeemer liveth*:

> What is faith but a kind of betting or speculation after all? It should be “I **bet** that my Redeemer liveth.”

That is, belief in God can only be achieved by making a concrete commitment to belief—a ‘bet’ which accepts the risk of losing.